# How to fix timeout connect redis .net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, redis

I have issue connect redis. What is the solution to this problem?
[image]

Comment: I too getting this issue. Requested help at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70278440/stackexchange-redis-server-keys-throwing-an-exception-if-key-pattern-does-not-ex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because StackExchange.Redis uses a single thread, if a request takes too long, it will block subsequent requests, so it adds a request timeout limit.

**Solution**:

1.To replace the driver, you can try to use csredis:

https://github.com/2881099/csredis

2.The redis operation is modified to all asynchronous：

[ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(Int32, Int32) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads?view=netframework-4.7.2)